# iOS - Firebase return null but field with data exists

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have database "Notification".

```
{
  "Notification": {
      "user_id": 
      "date":
      "type":
      "info": {
           "who_id": 
           "whom_id": 
        }
    }
}
```

When I start the application for the first time, I do fetch and I obtain all data from "Notification". When I add new data to "Notification", I obtain data without field "info". Only fields: date, type, user_id.

My code:

```
func fetchNotitfications() {
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Notification").queryOrdered(byChild: "user_id").queryEqual(toValue: FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let notificationDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                let notification = Notification()
                notification.setValuesForKeys(notificationDict)

                self.notificationTableView.arrayNotification.append(notification)
                self.notificationTableView.reloadData()

            }   
        })
    }
```

Comment: Please post your Firebase structure as text, no images. Text is searchable, images are not and when we provide a snappy answer, we need to be able to copy and paste your structure and we can't do that with an image.

Comment: I think if you add a quick *print(snapshot)* right inside your closure, you might find some interesting data. On another note; Keep in mind when you use .childAdded, it will iterate and return all children that match the criteria and will again return that data for any new nodes that are added that also meet the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

When you use childadded the snapshot is returned differently than you are expecting.

Instead of getting `

```
"Notification": {
      "user_id": 
      "date":
      "type":
      "info": {
           "who_id": 
           "whom_id": 
        }
    }
```

You are more than likely getting the following depending on how the query filtered the data.

```
["user_id": 
  "date":
  "type":
  "info": {
       "who_id": 
       "whom_id": 
    }
 ]
```